# binutils and gcc with LTO

Tags: c++, gcc, binutils, lto

I have binutils-2.25.1 installed to /usr/local/binutils-2.25.1, configured with

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/binutils-2.25.1 --enable-plugins --enable-gold --disable-werror
```

And I want to build RPM package - **gcc with LTO support** that uses linker **ld** from /usr/local/binutils-2.25.1.

I try:

```
Summary: The GNU Compiler Collection
Name: gcc-custom
Version: 4.9.3
%define full_name gcc-%{version}
%define binutils_path /usr/local/binutils-2.25.1
Release: 0
...
Requires(post): /sbin/ldconfig
Requires(postun): /sbin/ldconfig

%description

%prep
%setup -q -a0 -n %{full_name}

%build
AR=%{binutils_path}/bin/ar NM=%{binutils_path}/bin/nm RANLIB=@%{binutils_path}/bin/ranlib ./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/%{full_name} \
    --disable-multilib \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --enable-lto \
    --enable-linker-build-id \
    --enable-plugin \
    --with-ld=%{binutils_path}/bin/ld \
    --with-plugin-ld=%{binutils_path}/bin/ld \
    --with-as=%{binutils_path}/bin/as
make

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post -p /sbin/ldconfig

%postun -p /sbin/ldconfig

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/usr/local/%{full_name}

%changelog
```

After installing this package I try:

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.9.3/bin/g++ -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -fuse-linker-plugin test.cpp -o test
```

And get:

```
cc1plus: error: -fno-fat-lto-objects are supported only with linker plugin
```

But, **ld** from /usr/local/binutils-2.25.1 has plugin support

```
/usr/local/binutils-2.25.1/bin/ld --help | grep plugin
    -plugin PLUGIN              Load named plugin
    -plugin-opt ARG             Send arg to last-loaded plugin
```

Also, gcc-{ar,nm,ranlib} from /usr/local/gcc-4.9.3 have --plugin support

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.9.3/bin/gcc-ar --help | grep plugin
    --plugin <p> - load the specified plugin
```

Need your help, guys

**UPD I managed to solve the problem**. Just replaced

```
./configure ...
```

with

```
mkdir build && cd build && ../configure ...
```

and also added

```
cd build
```

to *%install* begin

**gcc-4.9.3/lto-plugin/congifure** script isn't written correct !!!

Comment: This may not be correct, but does the order of the `-f` parameters matter?  Does doing `-fuse-linker-plugin -fno-fat-lto-objects` change anything?